# Getting this name error whilst using django-taggit: name 'Tag' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

For my website, I want users to be able to add tags to their posts. But I get this error:
`python name 'Tag' is not defined`

Here is some code

Relevant code in models.py

```py
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images',blank=True,null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,auto_now_add=True)
    NSFW = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the relevant code in views.py

```py
class TagMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(TagMixin,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all()
        return context

class PostListView(TagMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'mainapp/post_list.html'
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')


class TagIndexView(TagMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'mainapp/post_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    model = Post
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Posts.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
```

And here is the form.

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','text','image','tags','spoiler','NSFW']
        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'textareaclass editable'}),

        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].required = False
```

I am getting the error in the Mixin, on this line `python context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all()`
Can anyone tell me why I am getting an error of `python name 'Tag' is not defined`

So far I have changed the casing of the word, I have changed the name, but none of it works.

Thank you for any help you can give :)

Comment: ... because you *didn't* define it. As with anything in Python, of you want to use something in your module you need to import it.

Comment: I imported the same import line from models.py and put it in views.py and it still gives me the same error

Comment: What "same import line"? The thing you need to import is the thing you are trying to use, eg `Tag`. This is basic Python.